# Camel 2.21.1 RouterBuilder OSGI Service getting exception due to Simple language not found in OSGI Service Registry

Tags: apache-camel, osgi, osgi-bundle

I am extending Camel RouteBuilder in order to define a Camel route, thus my specialized class is a OSGI component and on @Activate method the camel context is being created, like:

```
camelContext = new OsgiDefaultCamelContext(bundleContext);
```

After that the `camelContext.addRoute(this)` method is invoked, but when the `camelContext.start()` method is invoked the `org.apache.camel.NoSuchLanguageException` is threw. Thus, looks like there is a racing condition due to `org.apache.camel.language.simple.SimpleLanguage` is not register yet in OSGI SR.

**Note:**
There is no OSGI injection in route builder specialization, thus this one will be ready to activate sooner even before camel-core components.

Then, I'm wondering if it's a issue once makes no sense to my custom bundle add Camel internal dependency (like to SimpleLanguage reference) just to get out this racing condition.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do more setup of CamelContext if you manually create Camel in OSGi.

if you crate osgi camel context yourself, there is a few more setup you need to do
take a look in camel-core-osgi there is a helper class with a method that setup a bunch of stuff

Comment: Great! Are you mean the `org.apache.camel.core.osgi.OsgiCamelContextHelper.class `? I am invoking the `osgiUpdate ` method from there but times to times the issue get in. Do you any reference document about that?

Comment: Dont you have camel-core bundle installed and ready already before you install and run your own bundle? eg we only support Apache Karaf as OSGi runtime where you preinstall Camel via the karaf features. When you do OSGi yourself you are more on your own and all sorts of things can happen

Comment: And yeah that helper class is something you should use as part of your setup. Also your custom bundle can do a reference to for example camel simple language etc to have the bundle wait for it to be there before it starting. Well at least there is some logic in camel-blueprint that discovers what your Camel route are using and setup references to them so it will wait for them to be installed and in the osgi service registry (see the camel-blueprint source code)

Comment: Absolutely, now I got the idea! How about to change the start level of my bundle? In order to ensure that my custom bundle is one of the last to start.

Do you see any issue (apart from OSGI start level be a overwhelm)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering if there is a race condition with Camel-core activator and my custom bundle (no Camel OSGI dependency at all), because bundle language is register with the following invoke stack [bundle activation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lyAC.png)